# Ruby Array map for integers

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this Rails 3.1 ActiveRecord query:

`Show.where('event_id = ? AND id not in (?)', params[:event_id], @dog.show_entries.map(&:show_id).join(','))`

It worked fine when `@dog.show_entries.count == 1`. When it had more I had problems with the SQL generated, which was:

`SELECT "shows".* FROM "shows"  WHERE (event_id = 1 AND id not in ('2,1')) ORDER BY date ASC`

How do I stop it from enclosing the `2,1` in quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `join(',')`:

```
Show.where('event_id = ? AND id not in (?)', params[:event_id], 
  @dog.show_entries.map(&:show_id))
```